# Term for "Remainder in the Whole"

Tags: terminology, arithmetic, fractions

If I have a [proper fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_(mathematics)#Proper_and_improper_fractions) I want to know what the name is for the amount remaining in the whole.

So given $\frac1 3$ I want the name of the term $\frac 2 3$.

Comment: "Complement"?${}{}$

Comment: @MPW Hmmm... That may just be it. We do use terms lime complementary angle don't we? Which means the remaining part of a whole revolution.

Comment: There's not an "official" term that I've ever heard of. This is just a good descriptive word to use.